# How to fix brew Warning: Calling fails_with :llvm is deprecated

Tags: homebrew

When I upgrade software in homebrew, I got the following warning:

```
➜  ~ brew upgrade
Warning: Calling fails_with :llvm is deprecated!
There is no replacement.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2373:in `fails_with'
```

I guess this issue has some relation with julia programming language I installed a few weeks ago, but julia has been removed. How can I fix this problem?

#### Update:

Problem solved by `➜  ~ brew list | grep julia | xargs brew remove`

Thanks a lot for @bfontaine's hints.

Comment: For me, `llvm36` was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but from a different formula (a deprecated vpnc installed on an old computer).

A generic solution for others without `julia` who've also found this problem is to find the formulae with the deprecated compiler:

```
grep -R "fails_with :llvm" $(brew --cellar)
brew remove #{formula from above}
```

(These are instructions for the answer in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/131.  Credit to bfontaine's initial comments, but that was looking at taps)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `staticfloat/julia` tap (= a third-party repository for additional formulae) you had to use in order to install Julia. You uninstalled Julia but kept the tap, so those errors are still there.

The tap authors are aware of the issue and removed those `fails_with` calls [today](https://github.com/staticfloat/homebrew-julia/commit/7caf4d5da6836bd870247f11060dfeb4ed76c65b); you should be fine after a `brew update`.

Given you don’t need that tap anymore you might also want to remove it:

```
brew untap staticfloat/julia
```

Comment: I removed julia using `brew untap staticfloat/julia`, however, when I run `brew upgrade`, I still got `Warning: Calling fails_with :llvm is deprecated!`

Comment: @Nick I guess you have another formula in another repo that uses that. Something like `cd $(brew --prefix)/Library/Taps && grep -R "fails_with :llvm" .` should help you find it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, your `cd` command failed. It reports that there's no such directory. I checked the path `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps` in my system, `grep` returned nothing.

Comment: Problem solved by `➜  ~ brew list | grep julia | xargs brew remove`. This removed everything related to `julia`. Thank you very much for providing hints which results in the solution to this problem.